# storing name of the directory inside a path in a variable in bash script

Tags: bash, hdfs

i have path to directory as

```
old_file_path="/user/projects/dir1/dir2/dir3/$variable1/$variable2"
```

where variable1 and variable2 are name of directories stored in variable

i know in directory named variable2 there is another(and just one) directory  inside.I want to store the name of the inside directory into a variable.
Please tell me a command to do that.
since all the directories are in HDFS so command I am using is as follows, where oldMemberCount is the variable i am using to store the name of the directory inside variable2 directory

```
oldMemberCount=$(hadoop fs -ls $old_file_path)
```

But i am getting Error

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting? More information about whats going on is needed before anyone can properly help you.

Comment: In a regular file system I would do: `oldMemberCount=$(find $old_file_path -type d -print)`.  That works **only** if there is only one directory.  And it is recursive so be careful.